# JDBC getDouble returns 0.0

Tags: java, jdbc

I am new to Java and JDBC.
I am trying to get a double value from a database through JDBC and make a global variable equal to that value. Here's what I did.

```
public class Console {

    String sql;
    Statement stmt;
    Connection conn;
    ResultSet rs;

    //Category Total
    public static double num;

    public Console(){
            try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false","user","password");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

            sql = "SELECT sum(a) FROM table";
            while(rs.next()) {
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                num = rs.getDouble("sum(a)");
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(num);
    }
```

}

When I run the program it prints 0.0 although the actual value is not.

Comment: I guess this gives not just 0.0, it also prints a stack trace because of a NullPointerException. You missed that detail and this would also have given you a hint to find the problem yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get your result set *prior* to the while loop, and then iterate through it

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery(...);
while (rs.next()) {
  // and process your results row by row here...
}
```

Otherwise (as you've discovered) your `rs` variable is unset

Your result set won't contain sum(a) as a column name. You can get the result positionally (e.g. `getInt()` can take an index integer) or rename your result column (e.g. select `sum(a) as sum FROM table`) and reference it like that.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, I just fixed that but it still prints zero which confuses me.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't intialized the `ResultSet` with executing the query. Then you can loop the result set.

```
sql = "SELECT sum(a) FROM table";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql); 
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
   num = rs.getDouble("sum(a)");
}
```

You have been getting the results in the loop, but you have to do it before reach the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 0.0 because of the behavior of JDBC driver. 
From [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDouble(java.lang.String))

> Returns: the column value; if the value is SQL NULL, the value
>   returned is 0

To know that last read value was null from Resultset, you can use method [rs.wasNull()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull()) method. it will return true if the last column value read was SQL NULL and false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to assign a [column alias](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) to calculated results like `sum(a)` and retrieve the values using that alias.

Also good practice is to use Java's [*try-with-resources*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

> The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.

Also, if your SQL statement would return `NULL`, e.g. in case the table is empty or no rows apply to the conditions in your `WHERE` clause, the [`ResultSet.getDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDouble(java.lang.String)) method will return the value 0.

---

```
sql = "SELECT sum(a) AS sum_a FROM table"; // assign alias sum_a to the expression sum(a)
try( ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ) ) { // get a resultset object in a try-with-resources statement, to auto-close it at the end
    rs.next( ); // for the query you have, checking if there's a next row is actually not necessary; there's always a result for your query
    num = rs.getDouble("sum_a"); // retrieve the column value by its alias
} // rs will be closed for you at this point
```

Comment: A downvote without explanation, that's pretty lame. All solid advice in this answer IMO.

Comment: Yep, I agree.. +1. I'm sick of these people.